# Reading a .txt file into a 2-d array

Tags: c, file-io

I have a text file as follows:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
```

I want to read into a 2-d array of integers. The problem is the file provides no information about the dimensions of the 2-d data. I tried doing it as follows:

```
FILE *input_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
while (! feof(input_file)) {
    read = fscanf(input_file, "%d%c", &x, &del);
    if (read != 2) {
        i--;
        break;
    }
    in_data[i][j] = x;
    if ( del == '\n') {
        i++;
        j =0;
        continue;
    }
    j++;
}
```

This code works fine if the character after the last data-item in a line is a newline, but fails otherwise. What is the reliable way to read 2-d data from a file without knowing the dimensions of the data beforehand?

Comment: might be duplicate of How to input a data file into a 2D array (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246447/how-to-input-a-data-file-into-a-2d-array?rq=1)

Comment: 1. Make `mmap` of file, 2. Scan it for newlines (one dimension) and spaces between newlines (second dimenstion). 3. Allocate memory. 4. Read data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is to use `fgets` to read a line at a time.  You can then use `strtol` to read the values out.  Make use of the `endptr` pointer it sets so you can read the next value.

Alternatively you can make a short function to eat whitespace by reading a character at a time.  You can handle newlines in there.  Read until you encounter a non-whitespace and then put that character back into the stream using `ungetc`.  Something like this:

```
// Returns false if EOF or error encountered.
int eat_whitespace( FILE *fp, int *bNewLineEncountered )
{
    int c;
    *bNewLineEncountered = 0;

    while( EOF != (c = fgetc(fp)) ) {
        if( c == '\n' ) {
            *bNewLineEncountered = 1;
        } else if( !isspace(c) ) {
            ungetc(c, fp);
            break;
        }
    }

    return (c != EOF);
}
```

Comment: The problem with sscanf is that it doesn't keep track of the position of the character to be read next, like fscanf does.

Comment: Good point - on its own, it's not a complete solution for you.  You can tokenise the string using `strtok`.  Then use `strtol` on each token instead of `sscanf`.  Oh, actually you don't need `strtok` =)  Because `strtol` can return a pointer to the remainder of the string after parsing a value.