# How to save the contents of a text file into a 2-D Array?

Tags: c

I have created a text file called "thetext.txt" and ithas a quote.
The quote is:
"It would be better for the true physics if there where no mathematicians on earth.
-Daniel Bernoulli"
Now, I want to save this in a 2-D Array[200][[20], to count the words.
It only prints the string(It would).

What I have done:

```
void countwords(char word2[B][N]){
    FILE *read;
    char c;
    int i, j;
    int words=0, x=0;
    if((read=fopen("thetext.txt", "rt"))==NULL){
        printf("Cannot open File.");
        return ;
    }
    if(fgets(word2, sizeof(word2), read) != NULL){
        printf("%s",word2);
    }
    fclose(read);
    return ;
}
```

Comment: What does `sizeof(word2)` equal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a .txt file into a 2-d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738311/reading-a-txt-file-into-a-2-d-array)

Answer (score 0):

In C when you pass an array to a function it passes it as a pointer.
I'm assuming you did `#define B 200` and `#define N 20` to get this to compile.

Your `fgets` call is equivalent to:

```
if(fgets(word2,sizeof(char**), read)!= NULL)
```

Increase that size if you want to read more data.

Also your array seems to have an odd size to me because 20 characters is still not enough to hold that text, perhaps you meant `word2[N][B]`? 20 rows that can hold 199 characters each?

```
if(fgets(word2[0], sizeof(char)*B, read)!= NULL)
```